# CRM 2013 refresh parent process

Tags: process, refresh, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a process on account form that is updated in a plugin when a user creates an activity of a certain type. 
When the user returns to the account through the regarding object of the activity they need to refresh the account before the process updates. 
The onload script on the account does not execute.
I've tried to save & refresh in an onSave on the activity but that didn't work using;

```
if (typeof (parent.document.contentIFrame0) != "undefined") {
   parent.document.contentIFrame0.Xrm.Page.data.save();
   parent.document.contentIFrame0.Xrm.Page.data.refresh();
}
```

Any ideas?